# Asp.net MVC and Chart js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, chart.js

I want to show data that comes from databse with `chart.js`.

In asp.net MVC i have a controller that retrieves data from the database and shows them in view with the following code:

```
@foreach(var items in Model)
{
    <h6>@items.title</h6>
    <h6>@items.cuntr</h6>
}
```

How can I show `@items.title` and `@items.cuntr` in `chart.js`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Enhanced syntax

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-free-charts-using-chart-js-in-asp-net-mvc/
It describes all the relevant steps to work with charts in mvc.

Let us say that this is your controller method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      ViewBag.Data = "Value,Value1,Value2,Value3"; //list of strings that you need to show on the chart. as mentioned in the example from c-sharpcorner
      ViewBag.ObjectName = "Test,Test1,Test2,Test3";
    }
```

You can return the data in a view bag and pass them to the data property oif the chart:

And this is your view:

```
@{  
    Layout = null;  
}  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />  
    <title>Charts</title>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>  
    <script>  
        var barChartData =  
            {  
                labels: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ObjectName)], //the names displayed on the x-axis, see images below
                datasets: [{  
                    label: 'ProductWise Sales Count',  
                    backgroundColor: [  
                        "#f990a7",  
                        "#aad2ed",  
                        "#9966FF",  
                        "#99e5e5",  
                        "#f7bd83",  
                    ],  
                    borderWidth: 2,  
                    data: [@ViewBag.Data]  //what you returned back from controller. values displayed on the y-axis, see images below
                }]  
            };  

            window.onload = function () {  
                var ctx1 = document.getElementById("barcanvas").getContext("2d");  
                window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1,  
                    {  
                        type: 'bar',  
                        data: barChartData,  
                        options:  
                            {  
                                title:  
                                {  
                                    display: true,  
                                    text: "ProductWise Sales Count"  
                                },  
                                responsive: true,  
                                maintainAspectRatio: true  
                            }  
                    });  
            }  
    </script>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div style="text-align: center">  
        <canvas id="barcanvas"></canvas>  
    </div>  
    <div style="text-align: center">  
        Disclaimer:- This data is for demo it is   
        not real data it wont relate to any company  
    </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. i saw it. but i want to handle it from view. or simpler way.

Comment: what do you mean, you wanna handle it from view?

Comment: @masoudamirian, i will udpate my answer

Comment: thanks a lot. in this tutorial it use dapper. but i can't use this. because in dotnetnuke not allowed.

Comment: @masoudamirian, i edited my answer. no need to use dapper. Dapper is just an ORM framework, you are not obliged to use it

Comment: thank you very much friend. I'm beginer in ASP.net, what is Objectname in "ViewBag.ObjectName"?!

Comment: @masoudamirian, see now. i attached an image with some discription in source code

Comment: thanks a lot my friend. thanks for your assist. i try this and notify here

Comment: @masoudamirian, you welcome, if it helps, you can mark as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it directly from the `ViewBag`. e.g. `@Viewbag.YourObject`

I found that this project helped when creating charts , might need a few tweaks but works

[Link to MVC Charts Project](http://www.martinobordin.it/Chart.Mvc/)

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/charts-in-asp-net-mvc-using-chart-js/) is by far the easiest example I've come across just copy paste the 
code in your View & controller and bobs your uncle. you can modify thereafter

once thats done you can call your database like:

```
     dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Employee"] = "Someone";
        dr["Credit"] = rawData.Where(a => a.person == "Someone").Count().ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```